# How to read event data information from VSTS web hooks

Tags: c#, azure-devops

We are currently developing a service that integrates service now and VSTS. When an incident created in servicenow, based on the category selected the integration creates a work item in the VSTS. This part we were able to accomplish. Now we need to send updates from VSTS workitems, if any, to servicenow incident. We have created a service hook that captures the work item event details when an update happens to work item.

Now,the problem that I am having is, how can I create an event listener that listens to the web hook and reads that information. Is an example available on how to create the event listener from web hooks?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar with github webhooks. I´ve used an asp.net web api in azure because in .netcore it´s still prerelease. You can look for it [githubwebhookrepo](https://github.com/RichyP7/IEGProjektFHCampus02/blob/master/NotificationService/WebHooks/GitHubWebHookHandler.cs)
There is also a nuget package for vsts. I think it should be pretty much the same.
[nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.VSTS/)
You will get a context with a payload json in it and there should be your event type.

```
public class GitHubWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler

{

    public GitHubWebHookHandler()

    {

        this.Receiver = GitHubWebHookReceiver.ReceiverName;

    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)

    {

        JObject entry = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();

        return Task.FromResult(true);

    }

}
```

Payload info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=vsts